# Moodle web service not available for fetching quiz data

Tags: moodle-api, moodle-mobile

Is there any Moodle web API function available to fetch all the quiz data?

I know some quiz API functions are already available but none of them give the actual quiz data. I want all question and answers included in the particular quiz.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this data through existing moodle API function?

Answer (score 0):

Check mod/quiz/db/services.php for all builtin quiz related services

Comment: I checked but none of them returns actual quiz question, answer data.

Comment: Can you tell me how the moodle mobile app works for loading quiz data?